# OpenXml for Word - space "preserve" directive causes leading space after line break

Tags: ms-word, openxml

I have a confusion about the workings of the Word OpenXml elements `Run`, `Break` and `Text` when it comes to the Text's `space="preserve"` directive.

If I have a set of elements such as:

```
 <w:p>
    <w:r>
       <w:t xml:space="preserve">Medical Admissions are counted where blah</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:br />
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">Surgical Admissions are counted where blah</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

Then Word shows this as below - note the leading space before Surgical:

```
   Medical Admissions are counted where the  blah blah blah</w:t>
    Surgical Admissions are counted where the blah</w:t>
```

If I remove the `space="preserve"` attribute, then all is good unless the `Run` ends in a trailing space. Then I need to preserve the trailing space, but then the unwanted leading space reappears.

**Both `Run` elements have `space="preserve"`, so why does Word *not* show a space on the first `Run` in the `Paragraph`, but *does* show a space after the `Break`, even though there is no leading whitespace to be preserved?**

I've tried putting the `Break` element into its own `Run` element - same result.

Comment: I've created blank document and replaced paragraph's xml to one you specified. I see no leading space when I open document in MSWord(2013).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Unicode character U+2008 PUNCTUATION SPACE instead of the usual U+0020 SPACE. This will create a breaking space that is preserved in a text element within a run.